# Charlieplexing LEDs

Tags: arduino, led

I am attempting to charlieplex 9 LEDs using 4 pins of an Uno. I can light up an individual LED but don't understand how to light up several at the same time. CAn anyone explain the correct way to do this?

I have a version I'm working on online at Tinkercad here: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4vsov86j8ca-charlieplexing-2/

Here is my code:

```
const int UPPERPIN = 13;    //upmost pin
const int LOWERPIN = 10;     //lowest pin

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
  //update the leds
  updatePins();
}

//the function which manages the leds
void updatePins()
{
  // Each of these seem to work individually but not together.

  //LED 2
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  pinMode(13, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  //LED 8
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);

  delay(1000);

  //reset all LEDs
  resetAllPins();
}

void resetAllPins()
{
  for(int i = LOWERPIN; i <= UPPERPIN; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  }
  //set everything to high impendance, so it will not function in the circuit
}
```

And I have attached a screenshot of the wiring.
[image: charlieplexing wiring diagram]

Comment: why do you want to turn them on at the same time? I don't understand your question

Comment: That was just an example - I want to understand how to control more than one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you can turn on individual LEDs but you don't know how to turn on two LEDs at the same time I take from your question that you did not understand Charlieplexing at all.

Charlieplexing is a special form of multiplexing. It uses the tri-state capabilities of I/O pins to reduce the nubmer of pins compared to traditional multiplexing.

Let's take the most simple example

[image]

With both X1 and X2 as outputs having X1 high and X2 low state will turn on LED 1, X1 low and X2 high state will turn LED2 on

It is obvious that you cannot turn LED1 and LED2 on at the same time.

But you can make it look like they're on at the same time abusing persistance of human vision. If the you blink 1 led fast enough it will look like it is on the whole time. So all you have to do is to blink LED1 and LED2 alternatingly with that freuqency.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision

Comment: "I take from your question that you did not understand Charlieplexing at all" - definitely! I was beginning to understand that something more than simply turning the LEDs on was required. No tutorial I've read mentions persistence of vision and this probably also explains why testing on Tinkercad wasn't working well. So to be clear I need to cycle through LEDs (something like a for loop) turning each on`digitalWrite(11, HIGH);` and then immediately after off `digitalWrite(11, LOW);` before I go to the next LED. This should make it look as if all the LEDs are on - correct?

Comment: @garrettlynch just read the Wikipedia articles on Charlie- and multiplexing. start with a single led and a delay of 500ms. turn it on, wait 500ms, turn it off, wait 500ms, turn it on...  then reduce that delay until you cannot see the led off anymore. your eye will average over the on and off times. so at some point you'll see the led on continuously but with 50% of the brightness. now add a second led that is on when the first is off. repeat that test. then use 3 leds. each one 1/3 time on, 2/3 off. you'll see that multiplexing brings some brightness and frequency issues for many leds.

Comment: will try directly with an Arduino tomorrow.

Comment: I have 6 working now. Many thanks for the tips @Piglet. Is there a way to combat the brightness issue?

Comment: very simplyfied brightness is photons per time, if you reduce time you have to increase the number of photons per time to get the same amount of photons. what you can do is increase the current. most leds survive a lot more current if they are pulsed for short times. see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51427/high-current-pulse-on-led